# What are the easy way to send mail to 1lakhs users using php

Tags: php

we have million of users but my email news letter send to more than 1 lakhs. if we use phpmailer function its send at a time 100 limit email id . can any one help me how to send email to 1 lakhs users same time but my page take long time to load . can any one give some thread using php to send mail.

thanks in advance

Comment: I remember a discussion on meta about malicious intentions

Comment: Hi @muhkharjee can you explain if u know about the process?

Answer (score 2):

It is not suggestable that mailing to all the users at a time but is also not good that mailing one by one but just need to create an for loop for the user upto some limit,like suppose you have 20000users then seperate them into 500 into 40 chunks and make them loop...It is the better option you can do and it doesnt causes any crash your server..BULK mailing is not at all suggestable

Comment: I think you may right if we hold the separate of arrays of users it can execute one by one array users.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you take a look at [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), which has HTML support, support for different mime types and SMTP authentication (which is less likely to mark your mail as spam).

OR

Why don't you rather use phplist? It's also built on top of PHP Mailer and a lot of industry leaders are using it. I've used it myself a couple of times to send out bulk mails to my clients. The nice thing about phplist is that you can throttle your messages on a domain level plus a time limit level. For a complete list of features have a look at: [PHPLIST](http://www.phplist.com/details)